# Sign in to Chromium on Android not working

Tags: sync, chromium

I am trying to sign in to Chromium for Android from my Android phone and it is not working. I am getting the following error message.

> The account already exists on your device.

I tried to delete the Google account on my phone and tried to set it up again. Still, it is not working.

Is it not possible to sync Chromium on the PC and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has cut off support for any third-party Android browsers using the Chrome Sync API.

> A bug report was filed on January 3 on the Chromium bug tracker, explaining that attempting to sign-in with Chromium builds on Android resulted in an 'INVALID_SCOPE' error. After many reported the same issue, the likely cause was found - a recent change to how scoped refresh tokens were handled. This meant that only official Chrome builds could request tokens, and it only affects Android (Chromium builds on the desktop continue to work normally).
>
> If you're using any browser on Android that syncs with Chrome, you have probably already noticed it stopped working - and cannot be fixed.

[Source](http://www.androidpolice.com/2017/01/24/google-shuts-off-chrome-sync-api-third-party-browsers-android-citing-security-vulnerability/)

Answer (score 0):

```
The account already exists on your device
```

has to do with Chromium Contacts permissions in Android phone. In Settings/Apps/Chromium/
Permissions if you give Contacts permissions and clear cache and data you will see a dropdown with the gmail accounts that are on the phone. Then you can proceed with login and see if sync works.